# Google Maps plot summary count of records from Mysql

Tags: mysql, google-maps, geolocation, geocoding, geospatial

We have a Mysql table with approx 140k records (including lat/longs) and I would like to plot those records to a Google Maps Map to visually show user distribution globally.

Of course that number of records would be beyond the 2k point limit, slow an impractical to read.

Ideally therefore I would like to summary count the data so only geographic areas with say 500 or more would be plotted with a count number shown.

I am struggling to think through the logic of defining geographic region which will be the basis of the count. For example in some places there might need to one plot for a whole country and in others like the USA one per city.

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve http://media.shootandshare.com/map/map.html#people

I'm fine with the formatting and map plotting, it's the data base query I'm stuck with and maybe the changing query as the map is refocused e.g. zoomed in.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: To the person that voted to close this question. It is absolutely related to programming. We'll be querying mysql, we need to interact with Google Maps via javascript, and php on the server via ajax.

Comment: You need to have another column in your table, maybe more than one, that'll link a lat/long to an "area". Calculating this stuff on the fly, if possible, will take too long for any reasonable amount of data.